# Sending encrypted mail from php with non-ASCII Content-type

Tags: php, email, encryption

I am trying the below code to send encrypted mail where the cleartext is text/html and charset is utf-8.
For what it's worth, I cannot manage to get the mail displayed correctly (in MS Outlook).
As you may notice, I (meanwhile) try to have the relevant `Content-Type:` header *both* prepended to the data file to be encrypted *and* present in the `headers` parameter of the call to `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt` (and tried various other combinations as well).

While the desired content-type applies to the message when it is sent unencrypted, it simply does not work with encrypted messages. The result is always as if the "inner" Content-Type had been `text/plain;charset=ascii`.

I experimented with prepending the header to the data file before encryption only because I think I found some suggestion similar here on SE for a similar situation. But apparently this only makes the header line appear as part of the decrypted message (in other words, the file submitted to `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt` should *really* only be the "pure" content (as I had orginally suspected).

But having it in the headers parameter does not help, either: In the headers present in the enncryped file, there is a header added with the correct "outer" S/MIME content type, which overrides my "inner" content type given.

**Question:** Where and how in the combination of `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt()` and `mail()` should I specify the "inner" Content-Type of my encrypted message?

```
$hdr_to = implode(',',$empfaenger);
$hdr_subject = '=?UTF-8?q?' . quoted_printable_encode($subject) . '?=';
$other_headers = array(
    "From" => $hdr_from,
    "Content-Type" =>  "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "X-Mailer" => "PHP/".phpversion()
);
$mailbody = wordwrap($_REQUEST['message']);

//write msg to disk
$msg_fn = tempnam("/tmp","MSG");
$enc_fn = tempnam("/tmp","ENC");
$fp = fopen($msg_fn, "w");
fwrite($fp, 'Content-Type: ' . $other_headers['Content-Type'] . CRLF . CRLF);
fwrite($fp, $mailbody);
fclose($fp);

// Encrypt message
$enc_ok = openssl_pkcs7_encrypt($msg_fn,$enc_fn,$pubkeys,$other_headers,PKCS7_TEXT,1);
//$enc_ok = false; // for debugging: simulate encryption failure 
if (!$enc_ok) {
    // Will try to send unencrypted instead
} else {
    // Seperate headers and body for mail()
    $data = str_replace("\n",CRLF,file_get_contents($enc_fn));
    $parts = explode(CRLF.CRLF, $data, 2);
    $mailbody = $parts[1];
    $other_headers = $parts[0];
}

// Send mail
$mail_ok = mail($hdr_to, $hdr_subject, $mailbody, $other_headers);
```

Comment: The Content-type header must be prepended to the mail body (separated by an empty line), so it’s inside the encrypted part.

Comment: @not2savvy You mean, just as I do per `fwrite($fp, 'Content-Type: ' . $other_headers['Content-Type'] . CRLF . CRLF);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked that part. It looks correct to me. It's okay that your outer Content-type is overridden. Can you add the result in $enc_ok to your question, please? Also, did you make sure the `explode(CRLF.CRLF,..` works as expected as I'm not sure if it's only LF actually.

Comment: @not2savvy No worries. `$enc_ok` is just `true` because encryption does work (i.e., no problem with the cert);  for a minimal example, I might perhaps have excluded the test and the plaintext fallback branch. -- Yes, I noted that the contents of `$enc_fn` has only LF linebreaks, when (IIRC) CRLF is required. The explode works fine though, because of the `str_replace` one line earlier.

Comment: I was distracted. I meant to ask for the contents of `$enc_fn`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `PKCS7_TEXT` flag given as parameter to the encryption function.

---

My intended media type was `text/html; charset=utf-8`, i.e.,

- of **type** `text`
- of **subtype** `html`
- with **parameter** `charset=utf-8`

and superficially, the **type** matches what the name `PKCS7_TEXT` suggests. However, this flag is [described](https://www.phptutorial.info/?openssl.pkcs7.flags) as:

> Adds text/plain content type headers to encrypted/signed message. If decrypting or verifying, it strips those headers from the output - if the decrypted or verified message is not of MIME type text/plain then an error will occur.

To be precise, it seems that said header *and* a blank line (to separate it from the message body) are prepended, which turns any previously existing header lines (`Content-Type:` or other) into part of the body.

So the simple solution is to *not* use the `PKCS7_TEXT` flag (unless your message is really plain ASCII² text).

---

² It *may* also be okay for latin-1 text, but I won't count on it. After all the description quoted above suggests that an error will occur; then again, UTF-8 text gets decrypted successfully (i.e., without an explicit error), but exhibits the usual codepage related display artefacts .

Comment: Note: while non-ascii texts may encrypt and decrypt well, it is undefined how non-ascii are treated during by mail clients, so should definitely be avoided unless encoded properly (base-64 or quoted-printable).